# Bootstrap 4 col-sm-6 inside col-sm-6 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I m trying to use a div with class `col-sm-6` and trying to divide it again in 12 grids using `col-sm-6` and `col-sm-6` classes. However, it does not seem to work. `col-sm-6` inside `col-sm-6` is taking entire width of the parent and not sticking to 50% width as it should.

This pattern used to work well in Bootstrap 3 but does not seem to work in Bootstrap 4. I have code to prove it works in bootstrap3 but not in 4 below:

Bootstrap 3- It works: https://codepen.io/vishalgulati/pen/axMNRz
[image]

Bootstrap 4- It does not work - https://codepen.io/vishalgulati/pen/KYEzxr
[image]

Same code is used in both:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">25%</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">25%</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange;">50%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the answer is within the DOC: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#nesting .. you need to add `row`

Comment: even for the V3 you need row https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-nesting .. so it wasn't really working, you simply had *luck*

Comment: Thanks @Zim & @Temani! I understand this clearly now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootrap 4 use "flex" styles. So you have two way:

1) You need to add

```
<div class="row">
```

before your first two divs with class col-sm-6 and close it after.

You can see your modified example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZPOEz

2) You need to add flex (**display: flex;**) to you first div on cols-sm-6, that contain two divs.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="display: flex;background-color:yellow;">
```

You can see your modified example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRxeow

or add class 'row' to it - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZOWPO

```
<div class="col-sm-6 row" style="background-color:yellow;">
```

Comment: Thats one way. However, that would add one more div in DOM. Without that also it should have worked like it did in Bootstrap3, what exactly changed in BS4?

Comment: I add two way to solve this problem. BS4 now use flex css styles. They correct work in flex container. Simple div with class col-sm-* is not a flex container by default.

Comment: Thanks @inem88 , you saved my hours. Putting `display: flex;` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`col` will only works when it is the direct child of `row`. in your case, if the `col` is inside another `col`, it won't work. So you must wrap them with row. And since row has default `margin` of `-15`, you must wrap it with `container`. Check this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">25%</div>
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">25%</div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange;">50%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the second container is not needed, only the row is needed